# flutter: expansionpanel does not close

Tags: flutter, dart

One expansion panel was expanded, and when the other expansion panel was expanded, the previous expanded one was set to be closed.
For example, when panel 1 is expanded and panel 2 is clicked, panel 1 is closed and panel 2 is expanded.
By the way, I tried to close panel 1 after expanding panel 1, but it didn't close.
How should I solve this?

```
class _RecordState extends State<Record> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  int? _activeMeterIndex;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount:  2,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
            return Card(
              margin:
              const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 15.0, 10.0, 0.0),
              child: new ExpansionPanelList(
                expansionCallback: (int index, bool status) {
                  setState(() {
                    _activeMeterIndex = (_activeMeterIndex == i ? _activeMeterIndex : i);
                  });
                },
                children: [
                  new ExpansionPanel(
                    isExpanded: _activeMeterIndex == i,
                    headerBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                        bool isExpanded) =>
                    new Container(
                        padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: new Text(
                          'list-$i',
                        )),
                    body: new Container(child: new Text('content-$i'),),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
}
```

Comment: please provide a simple runnable code.

Answer (score 0):

you got the issue for the `isExpanded: _activeMeterIndex == i,` you must be used a unique index for each expansion tile and The callback gets called whenever one of the expand/collapse buttons is pressed. The arguments passed to the callback are the index of the pressed panel and whether the panel is currently expanded or not.

```
List<bool> _isExpand = [false, false,];


new ExpansionPanel(
                    isExpanded: _isExpand[i],
                    headerBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                        bool isExpanded) =>
                    new Container(
                        padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: new Text(
                          'list-$i',
                        )),
                    body: new Container(child: new Text('content-$i'),),
                  ),

// callback 

 expansionCallback: (int index, bool status) {
                  setState(() {
                     _isExpand[i] = !status; 
                  });
                },
```

Comment: follow the link for the [expantion tile](https://github.com/Jahidul007/Flutter_Roadmap/blob/main/source/dynamic_expansion_panel.dart)